# accessing variable - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `NSMutableString` var, which I have also synthesized.

This gets set in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSLog(@"Var val is %@@",curr_rep_date);
```

I have a button on which i call an IBAction and am trying to access the var value inside this method.

```
-(IBAction) moreDetails{
    NSLog(@"INSIDE IBACTION var val is %@",curr_rep_date);
}
```

But for some reason, the app crashes `(Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.)`

Please help me fix the issue,

Comment: what is "curr_rep_date"?

Comment: Could you provide the declaration and code basics of the class that you're using? I usually have the member variable, the @property, the @synthesize, so missing any of those might cause an issue.

Comment: That's exactly how I have declared the var property.

Comment: Show *every* line of code related to `curr_rep_date` (which, by convention, should really be called `currentRepDate` or something similar).

Comment: Here is every line of code
NSMutableString *tmp_dt,*curr_rep_date;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *curr_rep_date;

curr_rep_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmpRptDt];

NSLog(@"tmpRptDt is %@, Curr Rep date is %@",tmpRptDt, curr_rep_date);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably storing an object you don't own in an instance variable, so when you try to get at it again later, it's gone because it didn't know you needed it.

The [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) offers a simple set of rules you need to follow to get this right.

Comment: Is EXC_BAD_ACCESS because of memory leak ? Also in case I do not release/auto release a var, that should not be an issue. I mean releasing a var needed later can be an issue, but can it also be the other way round ?

Comment: @hmthur: No, it's because of the opposite (probably). A memory leak is when a piece of memory is kept allocated forever. In this case, your object is being deallocated too early.

Comment: Yep, think of EXC_BAD_ACCESS as a seg-fault or null reference exception.  One thing to keep in mind is that if control passes back to the UI, objects are free to autorelease in some cases.  This is certainly the case if you're waiting for a button click.

Comment: When you say "your object is being deallocated too early" where exactly should I deallocate the object? Actually I have not released curr_rep_date anywhere in my app. So can it still be possible that the issue can be caused ?

Comment: @hmthur: It's eminently possible for memory management to be the problem even when you yourself are not releasing anything, as explained in the memory management guide I linked. An object might be deallocated too early because you released it too early, or it might be deallocated early because you didn't retain it when you needed too. For example, if you write `someInstanceVariable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someNumber]`, that is a crasher waiting to happen.

Comment: So if we have someInstanceVariable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someNumber]
then we should have this as the next line
[someInstanceVariable release]

OR in dealloc ?

Comment: I have now used curr_rep_date = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease]; 
But still the app seems to be crashing because of curr_rep_date

I am totally confused why?

Comment: @hmthur: You do not own an object obtained from `stringWithFormat:`, so you need to retain it if you want it to stay around. It sees that it has no owners after the autorelease pool drains, and says, "OK, deallocating myself now." Ditto for the `autorelease` — you're giving up ownership of the object (so it could be dealloced at any time) but still storing it in an instance variable. If there's a property accessor,  you could use that: `self.curr_rep_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", someNumber]`. Generated accessors for `copy` or `retain` properties handle memory management for you.

Comment: Hey Chuck...You are absolutely on target...Using property fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you either use the setter (which hopefully retains the object) when you create the object or create a not autoreleased object?

choose one.

```
self.curr_rep_date = [NSMutableString string];

curr_rep_date = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Comment: ok..I added the line in curr_rep_date = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
and tried again. But still the app is crashing.

Comment: Don't just add the line without understanding what it means.   More likely than not, all you have done is created a leak while preserving the crash.